# Getting data from a table using a query

Tags: database

I’m starting with WordPress and I have a lot of problems and doubts.

I’m trying to display on a page data stored in a table of my database.

I have a table named Customers (id, name, surname, phone). Im adding code to the main page of the website:

[php]

$idCon = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');

if(!$idCon){
    echo "Error connecting database.";
    exit;
}

mysql_select_db("database",$idCon);
$query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS";
global $respuesta = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach( $respuesta as $row ) {

```
    echo $row->nombre;
}
```

$reg = mysql_fetch_row($res);
mysql_close($idConn);

[/php]

But nothing is displayed in the page. Can you help me?

By the way, how can i debug code in wordpress ? That should help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have custom table added and without more information helping you would be difficult. Please check [How to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what not to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: It's not clear fron your question if you have any level of proficiency with PHP as well. You are unlikely to just get ready-made solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you find solution here: [Wordpress Codex wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Best regards!

Comment: Please do not answer with links only, add an explanation and possibly code.